# RestKit resolve objects given an id or partial representation in JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, rest, restkit

I have a JSON array, something like:

```
[{
        "name": "John Smith",
        "occupationId": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Steven Davis",
        "occupationId": 2
    }
]
```

The occupation response looks something like:

```
[{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Teacher"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Teaching Assistant"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to allow RestKit to request the correct data for the occupations, given only their id? I know this can be done if the data is persisted using CoreData, via the `addConnectionForRelationship:connectedBy:` method, but I would rather that the data is transient, given that the server is local and there really is no need to persist the data. I'm also aware that RKObjectMapping does not support the identifiactionAttributes property, meaning I cannot (to my knowledge) designate a way to allow the class to declare a unique, identifying property.

Any help would be appreciated. I am using a mix of Objective-C and Swift, and as such, I do not mind answers in either language.